# XStream parsing

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am trying to pull out specific attributes from an xml file that I am trying to parse. So far I have been unable to figure out how to use only the attributes I need.

Below is the xml:

```
<document>
        <item name="id">some value</item>
        <item name="first-name">some value</item>
        <item name="last-name">some value</item>
        <item name="address">some value</item>
        <item name="zip">some value</item>
</document>
```

Here's my POJO

```
@XStreamAlias("document")
public class Doc{

    private String id;

}
```

If I **just** wanted the `id` value, how would I annotate my POJO?

---

**EDIT:**

Here's my update POJO.  I can't even get the attributes and values into a `Map`

```
@XStreamAlias("document")
public class Doc{

    private Map<String,String> items;
    // {"id"="some value", "first-name"="some value", ..., ...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be easy handled. You can use some built-in collection-related converters and receive map name=>value and then just get item with key "id". Or you can write your custom converter for that (not very hard way).

Comment: I cannot for the life of me even parse the above XML into a Map.  I keep getting "Duplicate field items"